# SQL Query With Multiple Sub-queries

Tags: sql

Building a Tag Based internal phone book and have created a linking table, but can't see how to join a select all people who are a manager and director from Aberdeen and Manchester.

Users

```
ID | Name | etc
1 | Frank
2 | Bob
3 | Bert
```

Tags

```
ID | TagName | Tag Order
1 | Aberdeen | 1
2 | Manchester | 1
3 | Staff | 2
4 | Manager | 2
5 | Director | 2
```

Linking Table

```
ID | UsersId | TagsId
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 1
3 | 3 | 2
```

If tag Aberdeen is selected it will show Frank and Bob
If tag Manchester is selected it will show Bert
I want to select Tag Aberdeen and Tag Manchester to show everyone
Then I want to select all people who are a manager and director from Aberdeen and Manchester.

Trying to work out the SQL is a struggle, any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What have you tried? (Show us your current query attempt.) Also specify the expected result, having the above table data.

Comment: Be careful with your expression of the requirement.  No-one in your data is a Manager ***and*** a Director, no-one in your data is from Aberdeen ***and*** Manachester.  `All people who are a manager OR a director, and who are from Aberdeen OR Manchester`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins. This, for example will show all people who are either from Aberdeen or Manchester:

```
select
      u.ID,
      u.Name
    from
      Users as u
      inner join LinkingTable as l on t.UsersID=u.ID
      inner join Tags as t on t.ID=l.TagsID
    where
      t.TagName in ('Aberdeen', 'Manchester')
```

This will select all managers and directors:

```
select
      u.ID,
      u.Name
    from
      Users as u
      inner join LinkingTable as l on t.UsersID=u.ID
      inner join Tags as t on t.ID=l.TagsID
    where
      t.TagName in ('Manager', 'Director')
```

If you want to select managers and directors from Aberdeen or Manchester, you need to select rows that occur in both of these tables. This can be done using `intersect`

```
select
      u.ID,
      u.Name
    from
      Users as u
      inner join LinkingTable as l on t.UsersID=u.ID
      inner join Tags as t on t.ID=l.TagsID
    where
      t.TagName in ('Aberdeen', 'Manchester')
intersect
select
      u.ID,
      u.Name
    from
      Users as u
      inner join LinkingTable as l on t.UsersID=u.ID
      inner join Tags as t on t.ID=l.TagsID
    where
      t.TagName in ('Manager', 'Director')
```

Comment: The OP requires that you *also* filter the list down to those users from your query that are ***also*** either a Manager or a Director.

Answer (score 0):

What you've created is an Entity Attribute Value table.

These are very flexible for storing additional miscellaneous data to entities without changing the data structure.  What to start recording a favourite brand of chocolate, and a new tag type and then add the data to the link table...

What they're very poor at, however, is searching through that data for entities *(users, in your case)* who meet certain criteria.

It is certainly possible, and here is the general method for doing this, but don't expect good performance over large volumes of data.  *(Search the web for EAV tables, optimisations and alternatives.)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN
  links
    ON links.UsersId = users.id
INNER JOIN
  tags
    ON tags.id = links.TagsId
WHERE
  tags.TagNames IN ('Aberdeen', 'Manchester', 'Manager', 'Director')
GROUP BY
  users.id
HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tags.TagOrder = 1 THEN tags.id END) >= 1
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tags.TagOrder = 2 THEN tags.id END) >= 1
```

This just selects every ***row*** that matches any one of your search criteria, then aggregates them to all by User to check that *at least* one of each "type" of criteria was matched *(at least one location, at least one job role)*.

Using this method means that you can *relatively* easily increase the number of and complexity of your search criteria.  Include all possible relevant tags in the `WHERE` clause, and then analyse the groups of rows in the `HAVING` clause to make sure that a sufficient *set* of criteria has been matched.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, I needed to select combinations from 5 groups e.g. Group1 = Locations, Group2 = Central Services, Group3 = Roles etc. Each group can have multiple selections with more than one group being relevant to each other, I guess that would be like Group1 AND Group2 AND Group 3, with everything in a group being an or e.g. Aberdeen OR Manchester AND Finance Team or Central Services or Training AND Managers OR Directors, I got around it using a SELECT Group1, Group2, Group3 from an then INNER Join for each group but I can't select just one group. in next comment

Comment: The text boxes are too short, I had to paste the code into a Google Doc here [link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KAl7_ty8r1fJOLs6yQMyEdn7dwaoN-LiVvfPHvr84SI/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

The problem is, I have 5 subqueries, e.g.

Comment: The text boxes are too short, I had to paste the code into a Google Doc here [link]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KAl7_ty8r1fJOLs6yQMyEdn7dwaoN-LiVvfPHvr84SI/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

The problem is, I have 5 subqueries, e.g.
--Locations
--Divisions
--Central Services
--Role
--Verticals

If I select tags for my phonebook that populates all ID's my phonebook works, but if I try to select one subquery like --Division, no data is returned from the SQL pasted in the Google Sheet, I tried Left Outer Join but no luck, any ideas?

Thanks
David

Comment: Build an example, including data, in sqlfiddle.com, or dbfiddle.uk, etc.  Also, vote and accept an answer on this question, and raise a new question with your revised details.

Comment: Thanks, MatBailie, your solution does work, binned all my code and used yours, the only thing, not all having statements may be selected, so trying to hide unselected till selected as no records show, any idea? I tried if exists, but not working...

  GROUP BY
  ctg.ContactId
HAVING 1=1
 
IF (t.TagOrder = 1)
BEGIN 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.TagOrder = 1 THEN t.id END) >= 1
END
--AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.TagOrder = 2 THEN t.id END) >= 1
etc.

Comment: @DavidArmstrong  Please put an example up in SQL Fiddle, or better still put up a whole new question.  Trying to interpret your meaning from comments is difficult, trying to read code form comments is worse.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me MatBailie, just got it all working, thanks so much for your help. All the best David.

sqlQuery = @"SELECT ctg.ContactId
                            FROM [search-contacts].[dbo].[ContactTagsGrouping] ctg
                              INNER JOIN [search-contacts].[dbo].[Tags] t ON ctg.TagId = t.Id
                              WHERE t.Id IN (" + TagId + @")
                              GROUP BY
                              ctg.ContactId
                            HAVING 1=1 " + tagLocFound1 + tagLocFound2 + tagLocFound3 + tagLocFound4 + tagLocFound5;